# How to pass image from frontend(reactjs) to backend(nodejs) and upload it to firebase storage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I want to pass image form frontend(react) to backend(node). How can I do this?

I will deploy my frontend in firebase hosting and backend to heroku. As frontend and backend will be in different place so how can I will send my image to backend? I want to upload image using nodejs. Frontend will just send the image to backend. I mean nodejs will upload image to firebase storage and will store download url in mongdb database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using formData... here is the sample code for api request in react.

```js
uploadHandler = () => { 
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', this.state.selectedFile);
   axios.post('http://localhost:8080/student/image',
   formData
);
}
```

Comment: it should work it's not the best for your performance