# how i can send compressed images to the server (not the original one)

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for sending the compressed images to the server when the form is submit but the FileList contains the original images, how replace them by the compressed one ?

here the code to compress images

```js
const Compress = require('compress.js');
    const compress = new Compress();
    const inputFile = document.querySelector('#upload')

    let dataList = new DataTransfer()
    console.log('datalist avant event');
    console.log(dataList);
    inputFile.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
      const files = [...evt.target.files]

      compress.compress(files, {
        size: 3, // the max size in MB, defaults to 2MB
        quality: 0.75, // the quality of the image, max is 1,
        maxWidth: 1920, // the max width of the output image, defaults to 1920px
        maxHeight: 1920, // the max height of the output image, defaults to 1920px
        resize: true // defaults to true, set false if you do not want to resize the image width and height
      }).then((files) => {

        for (const file of files) {
          const base64str = file.data
          const imgExt = file.ext
          const blobFile = Compress.convertBase64ToFile(base64str, imgExt)
          const fileCompressed = new File([blobFile], file.alt, { type: 'image/jpeg' })

          const image = new Image();
          image.src = file.prefix + file.data

          var span = document.createElement('span');

          span.innerHTML = [
            '<div class="col-xs-4 margin-table fond"  onclick="deletePhoto(this);">',
            '<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 75%;"><img src="/public/views/img/imageInsert/trash.png" width="15px"></div>',
            '<input type="hidden" name="name_files" value="', fileCompressed.name, '" />',
            '<img src="', image.src, '" height="auto" width="55%">',
            '</div>'
          ].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        }
      })
    }, false)
```

Comment: Avoid form submission with form action, insted make the function that calls on submit where you can wrappe your data + img files in formData and then using fetch or xtmlHttpRequest pass that to the server [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772036/how-to-pass-image-from-frontendreactjs-to-backendnodejs-and-upload-it-to-fir) or you can compress img at server side

Comment: I use form submission cause the back-end get all data from the form with the module [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) 
I dont know if i can use formData with formidable .. i will try